# Segmentation Fault with Otime

Tags: makefile, segmentation-fault, arm

I have a structure defined in h files and some elements of that structure are in compile time flag. The file is compiled using arm-gcc with -Otime flag. When I run it , it is giving Segmentation Fault. But when I remove -Otime flag from the makefile the code runs perfectly.

I am befuddled at this observation. Can someone share some insight on this issue ?

Comment: Since you mention the flag `-Otime`, I assume that your compiler is actually armcc, which has no connection to gcc.

Using -Otime, you have instructed it to perform optimisation for highest possible performance instead of the default which is smallest possible code size. This has significant impact on what types of optimisations the compiler performs, which can (for example) reveal coding errors that previously went unnoticed.

Comment: More importantly, without showing the code that faults, no useful comment can be made about the specific cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is never one easy answer for these scenarios. Certainly in the past, whenevr I have encountered such problems, its been down to the code, the compiler or even a combination of both. It would help if you could mention the version of the compiler you are using. It could simply be a Otime bug in the compiler, which is not unheard of.